# WebDriverManager - Problem with inDocker function

Tags: java, docker, selenium-webdriver, firefox, webdrivermanager-java

I am using WebDriverManager for over an year, but currently we moved our CI/CD to different tool. There is additional firewall that cut of external libraries. I tried

```
WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().browserInDocker().create();
```

and

```
WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().browserInDocker().linux().setup(;
```

but without luck. There was decision to move that drivers into our build repo but I don't know which drivers to move there.

```
io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.config.WebDriverManagerException: io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.config.WebDriverManagerException: org.apache.hc.client5.http.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to https://msedgedriver.azureedge.net:443 [msedgedriver.azureedge.net/13.107.246.38, msedgedriver.azureedge.net/13.107.213.38] failed: Read timed out
  at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.handleException(WebDriverManager.java:809)
  at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.manage(WebDriverManager.java:599)
  at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.fallback(WebDriverManager.java:825)
  at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.handleException(WebDriverManager.java:806)
  at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.manage(WebDriverManager.java:599)
  at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.handleException(WebDriverManager.java:799)
  at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.manage(WebDriverManager.java:599)
  at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.setup(WebDriverManager.java:287)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are behind a proxy, you need to set up it, e.g. as follows:

```
WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().browserInDocker().proxy("myproxy:port").create();
```

More info on the [WebDriverManager doc](https://bonigarcia.dev/webdrivermanager/).